# List the name(s) of professor(s) whose average teaching rating is the highest

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I got tables such:
Teaches(**cid,year,pid**,rating)
Professor(**pid**,name)

I compose a query like this(hopely it gives me all profs with ratings, but not the highest):

```
SELECT P.name, T.rating
FROM Teaches T, Professor P
GROUP BY T.pid
HAVING AVG(rating)
```

How I can embed query like give me rows containing highest rating(s) into this query?

Comment: add sorting to 'teaching rating' by descending

Comment: I would take time to define the table well, show us what are columns and their data type (Important to show data type) THEN explicitly say what you mean by AVG(rating) ?? what is Teaches(rating) ?? is that a number int ?? an array int[] that you want its average ?? EXPLAIN more

Comment: Try adding a `JOIN`.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Did you solve this one, OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this into your query:

```
ORDER BY 'column_name' DESC
```

where 'column_name' will be replaced by teacher_rating.

For more reference: [Visit this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the highest average rating for a professor, you can make the average rating a column, order by that column in descending order, and limit your result set to 1.

Try this:

```
SELECT p.Name, AVG(t.rating) AS averageRating
FROM teaches t
JOIN professor p ON p.id = t.pid // I don't know if this is right, but you need to have a join here, and I don't know what your related columns are.
GROUP BY t.pid
ORDER BY averageRating DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This will put the highest rating first, and limiting to 1 row will effectively grab the professor with the highest rating.